# Errors when building Z3 unstable branch

Tags: c++, z3, osx-mavericks

I've been trying to build z3 unstable branch in the past two days but unfortunately I got many errors that do not make sense. I have no idea where is the problem. I have OSX  10.9.
Here is the list of errors

```
....-MacBook-Pro:build ....$ make
src/api/api_interp.cpp
In file included from ../src/api/api_interp.cpp:35:
In file included from ../src/interp/iz3interp.h:23:
../src/interp/iz3hash.h:72:14: error: no matching function for call to object of
      type 'const __gnu_cxx::hash<char *>'
      return H(s.c_str());
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ext/__hash:38:12: note: 
      candidate function not viable: 1st argument ('const_pointer'
      (aka 'const char *')) would lose const qualifier
    size_t operator()(char *__c) const _NOEXCEPT
           ^
In file included from ../src/api/api_interp.cpp:38:
In file included from ../src/interp/iz3pp.h:23:
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:221:31: error: no type named 'vector' in namespace 'std';
      did you mean 'hecto'?
  ast make(opr op, const std::vector<ast> &args);
                         ~~~~~^~~~~~
                              hecto
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ratio:264:43: note: 
      'hecto' declared here
typedef ratio<                100LL, 1LL> hecto;
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/api/api_interp.cpp:38:
In file included from ../src/interp/iz3pp.h:23:
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:221:37: error: expected ')'
  ast make(opr op, const std::vector<ast> &args);
                                    ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:221:11: note: to match this '('
  ast make(opr op, const std::vector<ast> &args);
          ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:226:33: error: no type named 'vector' in namespace 'std';
      did you mean 'hecto'?
  ast make(symb sym, const std::vector<ast> &args);
                           ~~~~~^~~~~~
                                hecto
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ratio:264:43: note: 
      'hecto' declared here
typedef ratio<                100LL, 1LL> hecto;
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/api/api_interp.cpp:38:
In file included from ../src/interp/iz3pp.h:23:
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:226:39: error: expected ')'
  ast make(symb sym, const std::vector<ast> &args);
                                      ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:226:11: note: to match this '('
  ast make(symb sym, const std::vector<ast> &args);
          ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:231:37: error: no type named 'vector' in namespace 'std';
      did you mean 'hecto'?
  ast make_quant(opr op, const std::vector<ast> &bvs, ast &body);
                               ~~~~~^~~~~~
                                    hecto
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ratio:264:43: note: 
      'hecto' declared here
typedef ratio<                100LL, 1LL> hecto;
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/api/api_interp.cpp:38:
In file included from ../src/interp/iz3pp.h:23:
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:231:43: error: expected ')'
  ast make_quant(opr op, const std::vector<ast> &bvs, ast &body);
                                          ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:231:17: note: to match this '('
  ast make_quant(opr op, const std::vector<ast> &bvs, ast &body);
                ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:232:38: error: no type named 'vector' in namespace 'std';
      did you mean 'hecto'?
  ast clone(const ast &t, const std::vector<ast> &args);
                                ~~~~~^~~~~~
                                     hecto
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ratio:264:43: note: 
      'hecto' declared here
typedef ratio<                100LL, 1LL> hecto;
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/api/api_interp.cpp:38:
In file included from ../src/interp/iz3pp.h:23:
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:232:44: error: expected ')'
  ast clone(const ast &t, const std::vector<ast> &args);
                                           ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:232:12: note: to match this '('
  ast clone(const ast &t, const std::vector<ast> &args);
           ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:238:8: error: no type named 'vector' in namespace 'std';
      did you mean 'hecto'?
  std::vector<ast> cook(ptr_vector<raw_ast> v) {
  ~~~~~^~~~~~
       hecto
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ratio:264:43: note: 
      'hecto' declared here
typedef ratio<                100LL, 1LL> hecto;
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/api/api_interp.cpp:38:
In file included from ../src/interp/iz3pp.h:23:
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:238:14: error: expected member name or ';' after
      declaration specifiers
  std::vector<ast> cook(ptr_vector<raw_ast> v) {
  ~~~~~~~~~~~^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:383:3: error: unknown type name 'lemma_theory'
  lemma_theory get_theory_lemma_theory(const ast &proof){
  ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:417:49: error: no type named 'vector' in namespace 'std';
      did you mean 'hecto'?
  void get_farkas_coeffs(const ast &proof, std::vector<ast>& coeffs);
                                           ~~~~~^~~~~~
                                                hecto
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ratio:264:43: note: 
      'hecto' declared here
typedef ratio<                100LL, 1LL> hecto;
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/api/api_interp.cpp:38:
In file included from ../src/interp/iz3pp.h:23:
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:417:55: error: expected ')'
  void get_farkas_coeffs(const ast &proof, std::vector<ast>& coeffs);
                                                      ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:417:25: note: to match this '('
  void get_farkas_coeffs(const ast &proof, std::vector<ast>& coeffs);
                        ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:419:49: error: no type named 'vector' in namespace 'std';
      did you mean 'hecto'?
  void get_farkas_coeffs(const ast &proof, std::vector<rational>& rats);
                                           ~~~~~^~~~~~
                                                hecto
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ratio:264:43: note: 
      'hecto' declared here
typedef ratio<                100LL, 1LL> hecto;
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/api/api_interp.cpp:38:
In file included from ../src/interp/iz3pp.h:23:
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:419:55: error: expected ')'
  void get_farkas_coeffs(const ast &proof, std::vector<rational>& rats);
                                                      ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:419:25: note: to match this '('
  void get_farkas_coeffs(const ast &proof, std::vector<rational>& rats);
                        ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:419:8: error: class member cannot be redeclared
  void get_farkas_coeffs(const ast &proof, std::vector<rational>& rats);
       ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:417:8: note: previous declaration is here
  void get_farkas_coeffs(const ast &proof, std::vector<ast>& coeffs);
       ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:421:56: error: no type named 'vector' in namespace 'std';
      did you mean 'hecto'?
  void get_assign_bounds_coeffs(const ast &proof, std::vector<rational>& rats);
                                                  ~~~~~^~~~~~
                                                       hecto
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ratio:264:43: note: 
      'hecto' declared here
typedef ratio<                100LL, 1LL> hecto;
                                          ^
In file included from ../src/api/api_interp.cpp:38:
In file included from ../src/interp/iz3pp.h:23:
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:421:62: error: expected ')'
  void get_assign_bounds_coeffs(const ast &proof, std::vector<rational>& rats);
                                                             ^
../src/interp/iz3mgr.h:421:32: note: to match this '('
  void get_assign_bounds_coeffs(const ast &proof, std::vector<rational>& rats);
                               ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [api/api_interp.o] Error 1
```

I checked the first 2 errors manually but the code seems fine. PLEASE help

Thanks
Yaco

Comment: It looks like this is caused by increasing strictness of the standard headers in gcc. Can you say what gcc version you're using (i.e., what does gcc --version produce)?

Comment: *Comment from [user1214978](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1214978/user1214978):* It looks like this is caused by increasing strictness of the standard headers in gcc. Can you say what gcc version you're using (i.e., what does `gcc --version` produce)?

Comment: gcc --version produces 
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2
Thread model: posix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. I haven't seen any similar reports yet, but I just fixed a couple of problems that appeared when the new OSX and XCode came out. For details, see [here](https://z3.codeplex.com/workitem/74).

Could you update to the latest version of the unstable branch and try again (also re-run python scripts/mk_make.py). Thanks!

Comment: Note: After updating our build system I was able to reproduce those errors and they have now been fixed.